# Eigendecomposition in unconstrained QP

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, quadratic-programming

Can someone please help me to understand the following statement?

> Let $Q \in \mathbb{R}^{d \times d}$ be a positive definite matrix with eigenvalues $\lambda_{\max} = \lambda_{1} \geq \dots \geq \lambda_{d} = \lambda_{\min} > 0$. Then the following optimization problem $$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}} \dfrac{1}{2} x^{T}Qx$$ is equivalent to $$\min_{x \in \mathbb{R}^{d}} \dfrac{1}{2} x^{T}Dx$$ where $Q = UDU^{T}$ is an eigendecomposition of $Q$ and $D$ is the diagonal
> matrix with the eigenvalues along the diagonal.

Comment: $U$ is non-singular so $U^Tx$ is just much an "arbitrary vector in $\mathbb{R}^d$" as $x$.

Comment: Actually there is also an even easier reason: in both problems the only optimal point is the $0$ vector.

Comment: Thanks I see your point, but the x which solves the minimization problem would then differ by the linear transformation. If one imagines x as a parameter vector and one is interested in the individual parameters then these would not be equivalent, am I right?

Comment: Yes, that's why added my other comment, sorry. Both problems are simply trivially optimized only by 0.

Comment: And how do we actually need then that all eigenvalues are positive?

Comment: @Finn A negative eigenvalue and the minimum is $-\infty$.  A zero eigenvalue and the minimum is attained at a linear subspace of dimension $\geq 1$

Comment: I see, thanks. Now my only struggle left is how do we now that x=0 is the only minimizer of the first optimization problem. We need $U^{T}x=0$, which is fulfilled by x=0, but couldn't there exist also another x for which $U^{T}x=0$  (depending on U) .

Comment: @Finn Since $U$ is orthogonal, that cannot happen.

Comment: Oh yeah of course. Thank you. Really appreciate that.